# PDO in Classes: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object

Tags: mysql, class, pdo

I try to work with classes and PDO but I don't know how to fix the Problem.

With the help of var_dump($pdo) in RunQuery (after $pdo = self::$pdo_conn;) i get the value "null". Can anybody please help me how i can get the pdo object there? Or am I completely wrong with it?

index.php

```
require_once ('assets/socialbar/defines.php');
require_once ('assets/socialbar/mysql/classes/class.socialbar.php');

$ajaxid     = 1;
$getinfo    = "";

$getinfo = Socialbar::getInfo($ajaxid);
print_r($getinfo);
```

class.socialbar.php

```
require_once(MYSQL_DIR . 'config/pdo_connection.php');

class Socialbar extends Connection {

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function GetInfo ($ajaxid) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM uploads WHERE id = :ajaxid ";
        $inputs = array('ajaxid' => $ajaxid);

        //$stmt = $this->RunQuery($sql, $inputs);
        $stmt = parent::RunQuery($sql, $inputs);
        $rowCount = $stmt->rowCount();

        if($rowCount > 0){
            return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        } else {
            return $rowCount;
        }
    }
}
```

pdo_connection.php

```
abstract class Connection {
    protected static $pdo_conn;
    private $dsn, $user, $pass;

        function __construct (){
            require_once MYSQL_DIR . 'pdo_config.php';

            $host = $config['db']['host'];
            $dbname = $config['db']['dbname'];
            $port = $config['db']['port'];

            $this->user = $config['db']['user'];
            $this->pass = $config['db']['pass'];            
            $this->dsn = "mysql:host=" . $host . ";port=" . $port . ";dbname=" . $dbname;

            $this->Start();
        }

        protected function Start(){
            try {
                $this->pdo_conn = new PDO($this->dsn, $this->user, $this->pass);
            } catch (PDOException $e){
                print_r($e);
                exit(0);
            }   
        }

    function RunQuery ($sql, $inputs=null){
//      $pdo = $this->pdo_conn;
        $pdo = self::$pdo_conn;

        if(is_null($inputs)) {
            $pdo->query($sql);          
        } else {
            try {
                $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

                if ($stmt) {
                    $stmt->execute($inputs);
                } else {
                    print_r("Unable to prepare query");
                }

            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                print_r($e);
                exit(0);                
            }
        }
        return $stmt;
    }
}
```

pdo_config.php

```
$config['db'] = array(
'host' => 'localhost',
'user' => 'root',
'pass' => '',
'dbname' => 'images',
'port' => '3306',
);
```

Comment: Which variable "get(s) the value `null`", and why is that a problem?

Comment: probably because __$pdo__ is declared as static

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. $pdo in Method RunQuery.
function RunQuery ($sql, $inputs=null){
        $pdo = self::$pdo_conn;
var_dump($pdo) --> "null"

Comment: when I dont use static and just "protected $pdo_conn; 
PHP Fatal error:  Access to undeclared static property: Connection::$pdo_conn in line 32 ($pdo = self::$pdo_conn;)"

Comment: self is to access static methods or properties, $this when they are not static

Comment: ok. right. ... I changed to $pdo = $this->pdo_conn;
PHP Fatal error:  Using $this when not in object context in line 31

Comment: To use $this, you need to instantiate the object. You should read http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: There is written: "Classes defined as abstract may not be instantiated, and any class that contains at least one abstract method must also be abstract" So thats why i wanted to use "static" and "self::"

Comment: They can not be instantiated but they need to be extended. If you don't extend your abstract class, they are useless

Comment: Hey AD, thanks for your help too. I didn't instantiate the socialbar. Now it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO problem is your understanding or misunderstanding of `static` variables and functions.

So if you declare:

```
abstract class Connection {
    protected static $pdo_conn;
```

That means that you can access $pdo_conn even if you had not instatntiate the object of your class and did not pass the `__construct` so if you have not passed `__construct` what value holds that property?  Correct - NULL ;-)

so when you try to:

```
    function RunQuery ($sql, $inputs=null){
//      $pdo = $this->pdo_conn;
        $pdo = self::$pdo_conn;
```

What will you get? Correct `$pdo = NULL`.  And commented line looks as correct one.

There is no reason to declare and call `pdo_conn` as static property.
It could be `private`, `protected` even `public` but not `static`.

Try to instantiate the object first:

```
$socialBarObj = new Socialbar();
$getinfo = $socialBarObj->getInfo($ajaxid);
print_r($getinfo);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I allready changed it to
protected $pdo_conn; and
 $pdo = $this->pdo_conn;
"PHP Fatal error:  Using $this when not in object context in line 31 ($pdo = $this->pdo_conn;)"

Comment: That is exactly the same issue. Check my answer update at the bottom